# How to setup Out going email in Sharepoint foundation on windows7 machine

Tags: central-administration, alert, smtp, windows-7, outgoing-email

Trying to set alert on discussion post. The SharePoint development environment has set up on windows 7 machine with installed SharePoint 2010 foundation. 
I have to set up `Outgoing E-Mail Settings` from my central admin portal. Since I provided the required parameters. and tried to run

```
$email = "xyz@gmail.com"
$subject = "Test subject"
$body = "Test body" 
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite "http://myspsite"
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::SendEmail($web,0,0,$email,$subject,$body)
```

It returns `False` in result. However, I checked for the SMTP settings for outgoing emails. but everywhere the links given for Windows server machines like [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc288949(v=office.14).aspx), but not for Windows 7 to get his work. What all settings I need in my current environment ?

Comment: Hello! Is anyone there ? stuck on this guys.

Answer (score 0):

IIS (Internet Information Server) 7.0 in Windows 7 no longer includes the SMTP service. If you need that service, you might try the free hMailServer. and [read this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3cb23018-0fb2-4e0d-8e09-6422377c05eb/outgoing-email-setting-for-sharepoint-2010-on-windows-7?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

take a look this blog http://johanolivier.blogspot.com/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-incoming-e-mail.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is little hard to believe that SMTP service not in Windows 7, IIS7. Will check for hMailServer